# 2 CSV columns displayead as a one column on MAC

Tags: php, excel, macos, csv

CSV file looks fine if open it in Microsoft Excel on Windows OS, but if you open it on a Mac OS you'll see just a one column instead two columns (see a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATQo8.jpg))
What's wrong? ((((

test2.aristovapro. ru
https://www.instagram.com/p/BGCxRsfMDH6/

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
function outputCSV($results, $filename = 'file.csv') {

    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header("Expires: 0");

    $outstream = fopen("php://output", "w");

    foreach($results as $result) {
        fputcsv($outstream, $result,  ";");
    }

    fclose($outstream);
}
```

Comment: Hint: CSV stands for 'Comma Separated Values'

Comment: Check your excel defaults parameters when opening a CSV file. You can set the default separator character as "comma" or "semicolon"

Comment: I've add a "Scrape emails (Mac)" button with a comma separator, can anyone who have MAC check how it works now?